# Equivalence between norms in $H_0^1(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega)$.

Tags: analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Based in many questions and answers like [[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/246790/244803), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1401424/244803), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/652491/244803) ] and a comment a good comment here  [[4]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652491/is-h2-cap-h-01-equipped-with-the-norm-f-l2-complete?rq=1#comment1374450_652620). 
I would like to know that the space $H=H_0^1(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega)$ can be equiped with this norm 
$$\tag{1}\|\cdot\|_H=||\Delta\cdot||_{L^2}+||\nabla\cdot||_{L^2}+||\cdot||_{L^2},$$
this is the $H^2$-norm. Or, is it equipped with this one
$$\tag{2}\|\cdot\|_H=||\Delta\cdot||_{L^2}+||\cdot||_{L^2}.$$
Can I say that if $H$ is equipped with (1) then, normes (1), (2) and $||\Delta\cdot||_{L^2}$ are equivalent in $H$.

Comment: What are the assumptions for $\Omega$?

Comment: @Jack, we can assume that the domain $\Omega$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and with Lipschitz boundary

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the regularity of the domain: If $H^2$-regularity for the equation $-\Delta u=f$ is available then one has
$$
\|u\|_{H^2(\Omega)} \le c \|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)} = c \|\Delta u\|_{L^2(\Omega)},
$$
and your norm is equivalent to the $H^2$-norm.

If $\Omega$ is not nice, i.e., it has a non-convex corner, then there are functions $y\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ with $\Delta y\in L^2(\Omega)$ but $y\not\in H^2(\Omega)$.

Comment: Thanks for your helphol answer, the domain $\Omega$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and with Lipschitz boundary. if I'll use the fourth- order equation like $\Delta\Delta u= f$ where $u\in H$ is it done also???