# Elliptic regularity for Poisson equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $U \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ be an open bounded smooth domain, let $u \in H^1_0(U)$ satisfy the Poisson equation:

$$-\Delta u = f \tag{*}$$

with $f \in L^{2}(U)$, by the classical elliptic regularity result we have the following estimate see for example [here](https://www.math.ualberta.ca/%7Exinweiyu/527.1.11f/lec14.pdf) :

$$\|u\|_{H^2(U)} \le C(\|u\|_{L^2} + \|f\|_{L^2}) \tag{i}$$

Correct? However I see in some place the regularity estimate is written as follows see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2009328/360262):

$$\|u\|_{H^2(U)} \le C\|f\|_{L^2(U)} \tag{ii}$$

Which is a better estimate than the first one. How can I get (ii)?

---

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to prove $H^2$-regularity? this can be found in books (e.g. Evans), even the linked lecture has a proof.

Comment: The regularity proofs most of  the time assume existence of a solution and work from there on. This gives estimates of the first type. If the equation is solvable then an estimate of $\|u\|_{L^2}$ against $\|f\|$ is available (think Lax Milgram), which gives the seemingly stronger estimate  (1).

Comment: I know how to prove the $H^2$ regularity (i), what confuse me is the stronger estimate (ii) @daw

Comment: @daw  , Hi daw, is my understanding correct? Is there something wrong?

Comment: seems correct. seems ok.

Comment: Ok, thank you,It would be a bad thing if someone can not read my proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More generally, Let $Lu =  \sum_{i,j} (a_{ij} u_{x_i})_{x_j}$ be the elliptic operator. Then we have $$\int a_{ij} u_{x_i}u_{x_j} 
 = (f,u)$$

Therefore  by ellipticity:

$$\theta \|Du\|_{L^2(U)}^2 \le \|f\|_{L^2}\|u\|_{L^2}$$

Combine with Poincare inequality we have $$\theta \|Du\|^{2}_{L^2(U)}  \le C\|f\|_{L^2}\|Du\|_{L^2}$$

Therefore $$\|Du\|_{L^2} \le C\|f\|_{L^2}$$
Combine with Pincare inequality again we have $$\|u\|_{L^2} \le C\|f\|_{L^2} \tag{**}$$

Therefore combine with (i) above we get (ii).

---

However when $L$ has zero or first order term the last estimate (**) in this answer does not holds.